# php - Check if an array exist then append it in a json file

Tags: php, arrays, json, for-loop, ip-address

i store client's ip address in a json file named "log.json" in a format showing below.

```
[
    {
        "Country": "XX",
        "IP": "x.x.x.x"
    },
    {
        "Country": "XX",
        "IP": "x.x.x.x"
    }
]
```

i have come with this php code. it store data sent with get request. get request format and code is showing below.

```
localhost/config.php?ccode=XX&ip=x.x.x.x
```

config.php file

```
<?php
$new_ip = array(
    'Country' => $_GET['ccode'],
    'IP' => $_GET['ip']
);
$file_name = 'log.json';

if( isset($_GET['ip']) ) {
    if(filesize("log.json") == 0){
        $first_record = array($new_ip);
        $data_to_save = $first_record; 
    }else{
        $old_records = json_decode(file_get_contents("log.json"));
        array_push($old_records, $new_ip);
        $data_to_save = $old_records;        
    }
    file_put_contents($file_name, json_encode($data_to_save, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), LOCK_EX);
}
?>
```

but there is a problem. ip, which is already saved in log.json file, i don't want it to be saved again. How can i check if an ip address already store in log.json file then append it? i have a little knowledge about php. please, explain briefly. Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Decode the JSON, iterate over the result to check if it already has been logged.

Comment: `in_array('x.x.x.x', array_column($old_records, 'IP'))` - spares you the need to iterate over the data yourself.

Comment: you'll have this file eventually deleted. You should avoid storing JSON and overwriting entire file. Instead, simply APPEND new lines to a plain text file. You'll be able to sort the dupes out later

Comment: Agreed with @CBroe  as well as with Your Common Sense too.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks to everyone(specially @CBroe ).